# how do I get user input on an enumerator data field?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am working on a project where the user enters the kind of donut they would like, and i use that entry to create an object from my class Donut. Objects of the class Donut will have parameters of an Enumerator that was made into its own class. For example, the entry for the icing would be declared as an Icing data field, rather than a standard data type. here are the entries of the 4 classes holding the different aspects of a given Donut object.

```
    //COPIES OF THE ENUMERATOR CLASSES

    public enum Size{
        REGULAR, LARGE, HOLE
    }

    public enum Flavor {
        OLD_FASHIONED, VANILLA, CHOCOLATE, APPLE
    }

    public enum Icing {
        NONE, SUGAR_GLAZE, CHOCOLATE, STRAWBERRY
    }

    public enum Topping {
        NONE, SPRINKLES, NUTS, POWDERED_SUGAR, CEREAL, CANDY
    }
```

to Create the donut class that isnt the default, I need the user to be able to enter a size of type Size for the donut. I tried using input.nextSize() but that didn't work. is there a better way to input this kind of enum?
here is the constructor for the Donut class. Everything else besides size is edited with setter methods.

```
public Donut(Size size) {
        this.size = size;
        flavor = Flavor.OLD_FASHIONED;
        icing = Icing.NONE;
        topping = Topping.NONE;
    }
```

and here is the user prompt I have to receive the size input to make a Donut object:

```
        System.out.println("What size donut would you like? ");
            Size size = input.nextSize();
```

Comment: Enums have a valueOf Method you can use to lookup an entry from String, like `Size size = Size.valueOf(input.next());`. Note that this method expects the input exactly as declared on the enum class (uppercase with underscores in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Size size = Size.valueOf(input.next());` for String entry.